Rust async websocket
I am trying to spawn a tokio task inside my start_websocket method, like following:
    pub async fn start_websocket(
        &mut self,
        auth: &Auth,
    ) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let (ws_original, _) = connect_async(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT).await?;
        debug!("Connected to websocket");
        self.websocket = Some(Arc::new(Mutex::new(ws_original)));

        let callback_clone = self.callback.clone().unwrap();
        let websocket_clone = self.websocket.clone().unwrap();
        let ws_thread = tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                debug!("Waiting for message");
                match websocket_clone.try_lock() {
                    Ok(mut ws_locked) => {
                        match ws_locked.try_next().await {
                            Ok(Some(message)) => {
                                debug!("Message received: {:?}", message);
                                handle_message(message, &callback_clone, ws_locked).await;
                            }
                            Ok(None) => {
                                debug!("No more messages");
                            }
                            Err(_) => {
                                debug!("Error while receiving message");
                            }
                        }

                        debug!("Message handled");
                    }
                    Err(_) => {
                         debug!("Websocket cannot be locked!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        self.ws_thread = Some(ws_thread);

        Ok(())
    }

While the websocket starts correctly, I can see handle_message processing messages, however my main thread cannot get lock on the self.websocket.
I have to use this on main thread to subscribe/unsubscribe to items, by which different messages are received. The subscribe/unsubscribe internally calls to send_data:
    async fn send_data(&mut self, data: serde_json::Value) -> bool {
        let mut delay = Duration::from_millis(10);
        let ws_clone = self.websocket.borrow_mut();
        match ws_clone {
            Some(ws) => {
                loop {
                    match ws.try_lock() {
                        Ok(mut ws) => {
                            let send_result = ws
                                .send(tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Text(
                                    data.to_string(),
                                ))
                                .await;
                            match send_result {
                                Ok(_) => {
                                    return {
                                        info!("Data sent successfully");
                                        true
                                    }
                                }
                                Err(_) => {
                                    info!("Failed to send data");
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            info!("Lock not acquired, while sending data {:?}", delay);
                            sleep(delay).await;
                            delay *= 2; // Double the delay for the next iteration
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            None => {
                info!("Websocket not connected, retrying in {:?}", delay);
                sleep(delay).await;
                delay *= 2; // Double the delay for the next iteration
                false
            }
        }
    }

In above I always see Lock not acquired, while sending data message.
I am having little hard time to understand what could be the issue ?
I am suspecting ws_locked.try_next().await inside start_websocket, might be the cause?

Relevant types:
pub struct WebSocketApp {
    websocket: Option<Arc<Mutex<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>>>,
    ws_thread: Option<tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>>,
    callback: Option<Arc<Mutex<dyn WebSocketCallback + Send>>>,
}

I am fairly new to rust programming language so please pardon my poor design/code structure.
I am open for all feedback and comment and happy to share more relevant details.

Your call to ws_locked.try_next().await is holding the mutex locked across the await, so any code that needs to write to the websocket is unable to obtain the lock. This is why your try_lock falls through to the Err condition, and almost always will, except in certain edge case race conditions that will (probably) rarely occur in practice. Have a look at the StreamExt trait in futures and see whether you can split the WebSocketStream to share it across threads.

@CosmicOssifrage okay, thanks for input, will take a look. Is there any alternative to try_next().await ?

As mentioned in the comments, the problem here is your ws_locked.try_next().await call is holding the mutex locked across the await, so any code that needs to write to the websocket is unable to obtain the lock. This is why your try_lock falls through to the Err condition, and almost always will, except in very rare edge case race conditions that you are unlikely to encounter in practice.
In any event, even if you can find an interleaving of your current approach that enables both tasks to be fairly serviced, it is subject to risk of starvation, and introduces artificial restrictions; the underlying websocket is full duplex, meaning you can transmit and receive simultaneously.

The best way to solve this problem is to 'split' the ownership of the websocket's transmit and receive streams among different threads/tasks, so you can transfer ownership of the transmit and receive handles to different parts of your code. Fortunately, there is an extension trait futures::stream::StreamExt that allows you to do just this, specifically its split() method which returns a sink (used for transmission) and a stream (used for receive).
You can adapt your code trivially by importing the extension trait and using it to split your websocket in two, with each part being passed to the relevant task that needs to transmit or receive, accordingly:
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

// later
let (ws_original, _) = connect_async(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT).await?;
let (mut tx, mut rx) = ws_original.split();

// You can now move tx into the task that needs to transmit on the socket
// and rx into the task that needs to receive


You also don't appear to need to use try_next when waiting on the websocket, as you're in an async context, so you can simply block waiting for messages to be received with next().

I include herewith an example, which connects to the simple websocket echo server operated by websocket.org, sends a message every second for five seconds, and prints the result. It also has appropriate handling for shutting down the websocket after a period of time, and waiting for the tasks to return.
use log::{debug, error};
use futures::{stream::StreamExt, SinkExt};
use tokio::{sync::broadcast, task::JoinHandle};
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;

const WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT: &'static str = "wss://echo.websocket.org";

struct Handler {
    ws_thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    sender_thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    shutdown: Option<broadcast::Sender<()>>,
}

impl Handler {
    pub async fn start_websocket(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let (ws_original, _) = connect_async(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT).await?;
        debug!("Connected to websocket");

        let (shutdown_tx, _) = broadcast::channel::<()>(1);
        self.shutdown = Some(shutdown_tx);

        let (mut tx, mut rx) = ws_original.split();

        let mut sender_shutdown_receiver = self.shutdown.as_ref().unwrap().subscribe();

        let ws_thread = tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                debug!("Waiting for message");

                match rx.next().await {
                    Some(Ok(msg)) => match msg {
                        tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Close(_) => {
                            debug!("Received close message");
                            break;
                        }
                        _ => {
                            debug!("Received message: {:?}", msg);
                        }
                    }
                    Some(Err(e)) => {
                        error!("Failed to receive message: {}", e);
                        break;
                    }
                    None => {
                        debug!("No more messages");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        let sender_thread = tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    _ = tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)) => {
                        debug!("Sending message");

                        let message = tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Text("Hello".into());

                        if let Err(e) = tx.send(message).await {
                            error!("Failed to send message: {}", e);
                            break;
                        }
                    },
                    _ = sender_shutdown_receiver.recv() => {
                        debug!("Shutdown received");
                        let _ = tx.send(tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Close(Some(
                            tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::CloseFrame {
                                code: tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::frame::coding::CloseCode::Normal,
                                reason: "Shutting down".into(),
                            }
                        ))).await;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            debug!("Sender thread finished");
        });

        self.ws_thread = Some(ws_thread);
        self.sender_thread = Some(sender_thread);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(shutdown) = self.shutdown.take() {
            let _ = shutdown.send(());
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let mut h = Handler {
        ws_thread: None,
        sender_thread: None,
        shutdown: None,
    };

    if let Err(e) = h.start_websocket().await {
        error!("Failed to start websocket: {}", e);
        return;
    }

    // Simulate the task running for a while
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    h.stop();

    if let Some(thread) = h.ws_thread.take() {
        let _ = thread.await;
    }
    if let Some(thread) = h.sender_thread.take() {
        let _ = thread.await;
    }
}

